# In TDD , how can I make sure that the tests themselves don't get outdated (and mistakenly report SUCCESS)?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

**Specifically I am worried about this scenario :**

1) I write a class with 1 member variable and a copy function

```
class MyClass
{
private:
int grade;

public:
void setGrade(int x) { grade = x; }
int getGrade() { return grade; }
void copyFrom(const MyClass* src) { grade = src->grade; }
}
```

2) Write a unit test along these lines

```
void testCopyFrom()
{
MyClass mc1;
MyClass mc2;
mc1.setGrade(-347);
mc2.setGrade(10);
mc2.copyFrom(&mc1);
TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(mc2.getGrade(), -347);
}
```

3) After a couple months I add a second member variable

```
private:
int grade, extra;
```

and, (you guessed it !) forget to update the copyFrom() function accordingly.

In this case the unit test will ***falsely report success***. Have I done something wrong with the testing design?

Comment: I think in this case what you would really want to test is that the copied object is equal to the original.  This might suggest a test for equals() (depending on the language, of course), which would be a more natural place to expect changes when the class changes.

Comment: My draft solution is to add one more test which verifies that the data size of the struct/class has not changed since the last time. If it has changed (ie. member variables added/removed/changed type), then the whole test suite will need to be examined.

Comment: UPDATE : My draft solution does not work, because the size of a struct may be larger than the sum of the sizes of its members, due to data alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TDD means **test first**: before you change the code, you should update your code. In this case, if you decide to add `extra`, you should be adding tests for the API around `extra` (so far you have none, but maybe you'll want `getExtra()` et al.), and then, as you add and revise tests, you'll notice that you need to add `setExtra()` and `getExtra()` calls to `testCopyFrom()`.

At this stage your tests will mostly be failing (**red**), and you can then do the real code to make them pass (**green**), and finally, clean up and **refactor**, using your tests as a guide as to whether you've broken anything.

Read more about [red-green-refactor](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html)—it *is* TDD.

Also, you should mark `getGrade()` as `const`, i.e.

```
int getGrade() const { return grade; }
```

This means you can use a `const` pointer or reference to a `MyClass` instance to get the grade.

Comment: So, practically this means that the introduction of the new variable "extra" potentially affects all the previously written tests around the class.

Comment: @Wartin: yes—and shouldn't it? Really, though, you should be driving things from the tests, and tests are driven by APIs; if you add a variable, but you can never measure the effect of that variable, then there's no way a test can or should be falsified by it. Currently there's no `getExtra()`, and `extra` has no effect on anything within the class, so as @slugster suggests, the tests right now are perfectly fine. In general, though, yes: as a class grows, its tests will need to adapt to the new conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the test is **not** wrong - it is doing (and reporting) exactly what you set it up to do. A unit test doesn't care about the implementation of the target - it doesn't care that you have added a second property.

What *will* pick this up is writing another test that checks the new property after the copy. What the `copyFrom` test is really telling you is that the copyFrom operation appeared to succeed when you invoked it - it makes no guarantees about the *scope* of the copy operation, for that you need to craft separate tests.

Another way to look at this: just because you called a function and it returned without throwing an exception, that in itself is no indication of success or failure - it simply returned to the caller. You either need to change the `copyFrom` to return a success/failure indication (or throw an exception upon failure), or you need to do more inspection of the target's environment to determine success or failure.